# Multiple remove_all calls in same block

Tags: storage, map, remove-all

I stumbled upon an unexpected behavior when doing storage migration.

#### Problem Description

I want to clean-up a large `DoubleStorageMap` in multiple steps.
And that works just fine, however I also want to be able to test this using `try-runtime`. So I modified the code to recursively call the clean-up when `try-runtime` feature is enabled.

The code looks something like this:

```
        pub fn storage_cleanup<T: Config>(weight_limit: Weight) -> Weight {
            ...
            let limit = ...;
            match SomeDoubleStorageMap::<T>::remove_all(Some(limit)) {
                KillStorageResult::AllRemoved(removed_entries_num) => {
                    consumed_weight += deletion_weight * removed_entries_num as u64;
                }
                KillStorageResult::SomeRemaining(removed_entries_num) => {
                    consumed_weight += deletion_weight * removed_entries_num as u64;
                    if cfg!(feature = "try-runtime") {
                        return consumed_weight + storage_cleanup::<T>(weight_limit);
                    } else {
                        return consumed_weight;
                    }
                }
            }
            ...
        }
```

### Scenario

- Let's say that initially, `SomeDoubleStorageMap` has **3000** entries.
- Limit is set to **100** meaning that at most, we'll delete **100** entries in one call.
- I want to emphasize again that it works just fine when tested on-chain where each deletion is part of another block.
- When this is tested with `try-runtime`, it will enter an infinite loop.
- I've tried printing `removed_entries_num` and size of the storage map and it goes like this:

  - **First Iteration**

    - Initial map size is **3000**
    - **100** entries are removed, **2900** entries remain
  - **Second Iteration**

    - Initial map size is **2900**
    - **entries** are removed, **2900** entries remain
  - **Previous step is performed until stack is exhausted**

`remove_all` provides info as if something was removed, but the size doesn't change.
I assume it has to be related to the fact I'm doing it all as part of a single block.

### Question

Is this a bug or expected behavior?
I've checked the docs and the code but couldn't find why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. At least for now. I opened the following pr to improve the docs around this: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11182

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I've went over the PR you linked and watches Shawn's video about storage (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S8rmW8LD5o). It's more clear to me know what happens.